# Using ONLY subqueries WITHOUT using JOIN

Tags: postgresql

I want to extract the max & min salary from one table under one column grouped by dept and emp_name. How do I do this using only subqueries WITHOUT using Join.

Comment: Hello PunchPitambari, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide sample data and expected results to clarify your requirement.

Comment: `select min(salary), max(salary) from emp group by dept, emp_name`?